# Change image size of the "ComparisonPlot"

Tags: plotting, graphics, options

I work with the Predict function to train a neural network.

```
datnn =   Predict[dattrain, Method -> "NeuralNetwork",  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
NNCM = PredictorMeasurements[datnn, dattest];
CP = NNCM["ComparisonPlot"]
```

One of the outputs is the `ComparisonPlot`

[image]

I want to combine this plot with one other plot, for example :

```
Row[{CP, 
  ListLinePlot[date[[All, {1, 3}]],  ImageSize -> Large], Frame -> True]
```

The `ImageSize` of the `ComparisonPlot` is different from the other plot. For that reason I want to change the image format of the `ComparisonPlot`. Who has a suggestion to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Show[CP, ImageSize -> Large]` instead of `CP` inside `Row`.

```
points = {##, # Cos[#1  #2] + RandomReal[{-.2, .2}]} & @@@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {100, 2}];
dattrain = {#1, #2} -> #3 & @@@ points[[;; 80]];
dattest = {#1, #2} -> #3 & @@@ points[[81 ;;]];

datnn =   Predict[dattrain, Method -> "NeuralNetwork",  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
NNCM = PredictorMeasurements[datnn, dattest];
CP = NNCM["ComparisonPlot"];  

Row[{Show[CP, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True], 
 ListLinePlot[SortBy[First] @ points[[All, {1, 3}]],
  FrameLabel -> {{"predicted value", None}, {"xvalues", None}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True]}]
```

[image]